# Show Set is a Manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f\colon (\phi,\psi) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} (2+\cos\phi)\cos\psi\\
                                         (2+\cos\phi)\sin\psi\\
                                         \sin\phi \end{pmatrix},\ \phi,\psi\in\mathbb{R}$

be given. I have to show, that $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The problem is if I were to choose to points $(\phi,\psi)$ and $(\phi +2\pi,\psi +2\pi)$ then they have the same image and it is therefore impossible to find a homeomorphic map from $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I cannot find my mistake (which I assume is there, because the exercise is from a book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible IF you're trying to use $f$, restricted to some set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as your only chart. Can you think of another function, similar to $f$, which covers the set $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in a different way? One good example to keep in the back pocket is $S^1$. We see that $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ wraps around the circle several times, depending on how we choose the parameter domain $t\in[a,b]$. As you point out, we don't want this wrapping because then our chart won't be a homeomorphism. Okay, so lets restrict this chart a bit. Let's use the chart $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ with parameter domain $(0,2\pi)$. Great! Not too hard to see that this is a homeomorphism onto its image. Problem is, you now notice that we've missed the point $(1,0)$ in the plane, right? Well, we just use a new chart! So to cover $(1,0)$, use the chart $t\mapsto(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ with parameter domain, say, $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. It is a little bit weird that our two charts have the same "formula", but morally there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: This would make my exercise quite easy then. I just restrict the domain of $f$ to $(0,2\pi)$ and would get my first chart. Then I just do the same as you did and pick another domain from which I obtain my second chart. Is this correct?

Comment: You can't restrict to $(0,2\pi)$ for $f$, you have to restrict to some open rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Personally, I would have to play around with the plots in Mathematica or something to see which domains work. I can tell you, though, that $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a torus. If this parametrization works the way I think it does, wrapping around the two circles, then I think you should be able to do it with two charts. Again, I'd probably have to bust out some graphing utilities to see it for myself. The nice thing about using one formula is that you only have to show its a diffeomorphism once.

Comment: If you happen to play around with it sometime, I would love to know your results! Nevertheless, I am pretty sure the two charts work from what I have seen. Thanks.